# Installation of GPAC

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install gpac on my pc, i'm running ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32-bit.

The problem I have is when I try to install the gpac package i get the following error:
gcc: error: unrecognised option ‘--warn-common’
make[1]: *** [libgpac.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/gpac/src'
make: *** [lib] Error 2

Can anyone help me with this because I can't seem to find a solution

Answer (score 3):

GPAC is in the [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gpac&searchon=names) you dont need to implement difficult compilation methods to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gpac
```